# How can I implement an imputation algorithm with constraints on aggregate values?

Tags: imputation, r-mice

I have a firm level dataset with missing that I would like to impute. I know the aggregate value of some vars, how can I implement a MICE type imputation algorithm that considers also the aggregate value?

I mostly use R

Comment: Can you supply some sample code? It does not have to be the actual internal data that you use. I create sample code often that is a reduced version of the original

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.